# Scroll div with jquery, fade out when footer is reached

Tags: jquery, scroll, fade

I have a long page of content that I'd like to make a toolbar for that would scroll with and hover over the top of the page. I have managed to get that done, however I need to also make it so that once the footer div is reached on scroll, that the div that is hovering will fade out. Here is what I have done so far:

```
function sticky_relocate() {

var window_top = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
var div_top = jQuery('#anchor').offset().top;
var footer_top = jQuery('.footer-container').offset().top;
//var length = jQuery('.main').height() - jQuery('#fixed-toolbar').height() + jQuery('.main').offset().top;
//var height = jQuery('.main').height() + 'px';

if (window_top > div_top) {
    jQuery('#fixed-toolbar').addClass('fixed');
} else if (window_top > footer_top) {
    jQuery('#fixed-toolbar').removeClass('fixed');
} else {
    jQuery('#fixed-toolbar').removeClass('fixed');
}

//console.log(height);
}

jQuery(function () {
jQuery(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
sticky_relocate();
});
```

Here is a rough representation of my html:

```
<div id="anchor">
    <div id="fixed-toolbar">
        This is a test
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    Static text blocks<br> 
</div>

<div class="footer-container">
    This is the footer<br>
</div>
```

Can you tell me where I'm going wrong? I can't figure out how to fade out the scrolling div once the 'footer-container' div is reached.

I have created a JSFiddle, here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/5bcaz88p/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are a working example http://jsfiddle.net/5bcaz88p/2/

Your else/if conditions were false, basically as you have them it will never go in the second if (**if (window_top > footer_top)** ) because window_top will always satisfy the first condition (it will be bigger than div_top) and it will never go to the second if. The second if should be as a separate condition :)

```
function sticky_relocate() {

    var window_top = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    var div_top = jQuery('#anchor').offset().top;
    var footer_top = jQuery('.footer-container').offset().top;

    if (window_top > div_top) {
        jQuery('#fixed-toolbar').addClass('fixed');
    } else {
        jQuery('#fixed-toolbar').removeClass('fixed');
    }

    if (window_top > footer_top) {
        jQuery('#fixed-toolbar').removeClass('fixed');
    }

}

jQuery(function () {
    jQuery(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

Comment: Ah! Of course! Can't believe it was something so simple. Thanks Bojan.

Comment: Glad that I could help :) You can accept the answer so the question can be closed :)